# DB2 Security and necessary call to SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE')

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a couple of Flyway scripts which do ALTER TABLE statements on two tables. My problem is that DB2 seems to be insisting on what I think is a DBA/privileged command just to insert into an altered table. For development purposes, I'm hosting my database in a local docker container and it's cheap for me to do anything to that, I'm really more concerned about how it will be when deployed to test and production. I'd prefer as much as possible to not have any human intervention should the table need to be rebuilt. My choices seem to be:

1. Manually run the REORG statement
2. Add the REORG to the Flyway script, somehow force DB2 to not complain about running this stored procedure.
3. Hopefully some DB2 guru has a magic command that forces DB2 to just work.

If I choose option 1, someone has to be at the keyboard at the right time to call the reorg command. If I choose option 2, I'm asking the database security to be opened up such that the application user has access to what might be highly privileged stored procedures. I'd like to know if my concerns for #2 are warranted. My preference is for option 3 and for someone to tell me what that is.

The apparently necessary command is

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE COST_RULES.LOW_DLL_EXCEP');
```

Without this, I get Error SQLSTATE 57016 -668
Message    : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, SQLERRMC=7;COST_RULES.LOW_DLL_EXCEP, DRIVER=4.19.66
when executing:

```
INSERT INTO LOW_DLL_EXCEP(COUNTRY, COUNTRY_CD, DIVISION, ACCOUNT_ID, MIN_AMOUNT)VALUES('Spain',838,'DD','ACCTID', 40)
```

The IBM reported message for this SQLSTATE is "The table cannot be accessed, because it is inactive." The overwhelming solution to this is call CMD_ADMIN(REORG TABLE).

The DDL for my table being inserted into is

```
-- COST_RULES.LOW_DLL_EXCEP definition

CREATE TABLE "COST_RULES"."LOW_DLL_EXCEP"  (
          "LOW_DLL_EXCEP_ID" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (  
            START WITH +1  
            INCREMENT BY +1  
            MINVALUE +1  
            MAXVALUE +9223372036854775807  
            NO CYCLE  
            CACHE 20  
            NO ORDER ) , 
          "COUNTRY" VARCHAR(20 OCTETS) , 
          "COUNTRY_CD" INTEGER , 
          "DIVISION" VARCHAR(2 OCTETS) , 
          "ACCOUNT_ID" VARCHAR(10 OCTETS) , 
          "MIN_AMOUNT" DECIMAL(15,2) )   
         IN "USERSPACE1"  
         ORGANIZE BY ROW  ;
ALTER TABLE "COST_RULES"."LOW_DLL_EXCEP" 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY
        ("LOW_DLL_EXCEP_ID")
    ENFORCED ;
ALTER TABLE "COST_RULES"."LOW_DLL_EXCEP" ALTER COLUMN "LOW_DLL_EXCEP_ID" RESTART WITH 21 ;

GRANT CONTROL ON TABLE "COST_RULES"."LOW_DLL_EXCEP" TO USER "DB2INST1"  ;
GRANT CONTROL ON INDEX "SYSIBM  "."SQL210303080501560" TO USER "DB2INST1"  ;
```

However, if I add the CALL to the Flyway script, sometimes I get DB2 SQLCODE=-1646 relating to some error with running an admin stored procedure as a fenced user (my best understanding of situation). Please see related [DB2 SQLCODE=-1646 on CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513123/db2-sqlcode-1646-on-call-sysproc-admin-cmd-reorg-table) for more information.

I'm running DB2 LUW

```
[db2inst1@6a9bca535632 /]$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11055" with level
identifier "0606010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.5.0", "s2011011400", "DYN2011011400AMD64",
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5".
```

Comment: [SQL1646 when trying to call a non-SQL stored procedure or UDF](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql1646-when-trying-call-non-sql-stored-procedure-or-udf). The routine tries to access some files  in OS from the owner of the ~db2inst1/sqllib/adm/.fenced files do fails to do this. Some file permittions in OS are changed probably. Check if such a user exists. Stop the instance and run from root: `DB2DIR/instance/db2iupdt -u db2fenc1 db2inst1`. `db2fenc1` here is your fenced user name, `db2inst1` is your instance name, `DB2DIR` - the db2 code installation path.

Comment: The fenced user exists. Is the reorg statement a security concern? What does the db3iupdt command do? Thx